# Pandas - For a given date in one column, how many dates in another column are less than that date?

Tags: python, pandas, date, numpy, dataframe

I have the following table:

```
id | invoice_date | payment_date
--------------------------------
1  | 2017-03-01   | 2017-03-03
1  | 2017-03-04   | 2017-03-06
1  | 2017-03-04   | 2017-03-11
1  | 2017-03-15   | 2017-03-16
1  | 2017-03-21   | 2017-03-31
2  | 2017-01-22   | 2017-01-22
2  | 2017-01-24   | 2017-01-25
```

and I want to know: for any given index in the table, how many payment dates with a lesser index are less than the index's invoice date? Namely, for a given invoice date, how many payment dates occur earlier? Ideally, I'd like to do this for each id (grouped-by), so I have something like:

```
id | invoice_date | payment_date | num_pay_dates_less_than_inv_date
------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2017-03-01   | 2017-03-03   | 0
1  | 2017-03-04   | 2017-03-06   | 1
1  | 2017-03-04   | 2017-03-11   | 1
1  | 2017-03-15   | 2017-03-16   | 3
1  | 2017-03-21   | 2017-03-31   | 4
2  | 2017-01-22   | 2017-01-22   | 0
2  | 2017-01-24   | 2017-01-25   | 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy solution. Use broadcasted comparison, followed by a `cumsum` operation along the first axis. Finally, extract the diagonal elements and assign to `df`.

```
v = (df.invoice_date[:, None] > df.payment_date.values).cumsum(1)
df['num_pay_dates_less_than_inv_date'] = v[np.diag_indices_from(v)]
```

```
df

   id invoice_date payment_date  num_pay_dates_less_than_inv_date
0   1   2017-03-01   2017-03-03                                 0
1   1   2017-03-04   2017-03-06                                 1
2   1   2017-03-04   2017-03-11                                 1
3   1   2017-03-15   2017-03-16                                 3
4   1   2017-03-21   2017-03-31                                 4
5   2   2017-01-22   2017-01-22                                 0
6   2   2017-01-24   2017-01-25                                 1
```

This requires both columns to be in datetime format (otherwise, the comparison is lexicographical, which is usually okay, but it would depend on your date format at that point).

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Seems so obvious to me now. Do you know if there is a faster method for this (assuming hundreds of rows per id, for thousands of ids)?

Comment: @boldbrandywine This is by far the fastest method (to my knowledge), short of writing _C_ code. Unfortunately, for larger datasets, this becomes a memory hungry method. You might want to consider writing a loop in that case.

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark this as answered and use it to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use @COLDSPEEDs recommendation of writing a loop given his/her answer. On a dataframe of size 50K, the loop implementation performs 20x faster than the non-loop implementation. The dataframe's columns are id, value1, and value2.

```
def f(grp):

    dxv = {}
    for ix, val in zip(grp.index, grp.value1[:, None]):
        if (val > grp.value2.values[:ix]).any():
            dxv[ix] = (val > grp.value2.values[:ix]).cumsum()[-1]
        else:
            dxv[ix] = 0
    return pd.Series(dxv)
```

This works well for my case using:

```
df['num_pay_dates_less_than_inv_date'] = \
df.groupby(['id']).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Feel free to optimize this further.